# Who are these lords at the council of lords?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

So in the council in *Game of Thrones* S08E06 where the new King is elected in we see 15 (if I counted correctly) remaining Lords and Ladies representing various areas/houses. I can easily see:

- Sansa, Bran and Arya for Stark/Winterfell/The North
- Gendry for house Baratheon and presumably the Stormlands
- Ser Davos for house Seaworth
- Brienne for house Tarth
- An unnamed Prince of Dorne
- Yara for Greyjoy and by extension the Iron Isles.
- Robin for house Arryn, supported by Yohn for house Royce, combined for Vale & Mountain.
- Edmure for house Tully and presumably the riverlands.

However, there are four lords I do not think we've seen before, do we know their house, who they represent, and/or their names?

Next to Yara:
[image]

Next to John Royce:
[image]

Next to Gendry:
[image]

Next to Edmure and Sam:
[image]

Comment: They're red shirts as far as I can tell.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Living and learning [Red shirt](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=red%20shirt)

Comment: Not really, though, since that would imply them being there just to die, no? (Unless I'm wrong on how that council went.)

Comment: A community Wiki would be good for this question.

Comment: @Charles but why?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

> [**Une**](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Une): The character's name is not mentioned in the show or in the credits. However, actor Michael Benbaruk's [CV](https://cre8talent.co.uk/portfolio/michael-benbaruk/)

But we don't know what is Une now, house name or character name.

---

[image]

> [**Unnamed Reach Lord**](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Reach_Lord)
>
> The name and House of this lord are not specified in the TV series. The principal surviving houses of the Reach whose lords are as of yet unseen are House Ashford, House Hightower, House Fossoway, House Florent, House Oakheart, House Rowan, and House Redwyne.

Fan [speculation](https://winteriscoming.net/2019/05/20/was-that-howland-reed-at-the-dragonpit-in-the-game-of-thrones-finale/) is he is **Howland Reed**.

---

[image]

> [**Unnamed Northern Lord**](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Northern_Lord): he name and House of this lord are not specified in the TV series. The principal surviving northern houses whose lords are as of yet unseen are House Hornwood, House Tallhart, House Flint, and House Dormund.

From his agency's [twitter account](https://twitter.com/mcleanwilliams/status/1130511140415582209):

[image]

---

[image]

> [**Unnamed Vale Lord**](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Vale_Lord): The name and House of this lord are not specified in the TV series. The principal surviving houses of the Vale whose lords are as of yet unseen are House Corbray, House Lynderly, and House Moore.

Answer (score 2):

### We don't know

There are some [speculations](https://www.cosmopolitan.com/uk/entertainment/a27526297/game-of-thrones-finale-who-is-on-westeros-great-council-voted-bran-king-a-guide/) but currently, we don't know who these new faces are, and as this is the series finale, it will probably stay that way.

A few speculations below:

> Maybe **Howland Reed**
>
> We’ve not seen his face before, and he doesn’t have any sigils on his person. He’s also not dressed like a Northener or a Southener, so it’s not clear which house he’s the head of at first glance.
>
> But a number of viewers are speculating that he is in fact Howland Reed: Jojen and Meera Reed’s dad. House Reed sits in the Neck of the Westeros map, right between the North and the South.
>
> [image: Reed]

Maybe **a representative from the reach**

> Word on the street is he’s a representative from the Reach, which is where both the Highgarden and Tarly houses sit. But without a sigil on his clothes, we can only assume that’s what his deal is.
>
> [image: reach]

By the clothes, a northern prince, but no word on him.

> [image: northern]

Unnamed:

> [image: unnamed]